# How to remove dragged row trail in NSTable View?

Tags: nstableview

When I am dragging a row from NSTableView. It shows a shadow trail of the specific row which is being dragged. Didn't found any method to remove it. I also tried to subclass NSTableRowView. Tried all the methods, didn't found any solution.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: I have multi columns table. I want a particular cell to be dragged in a table, instead of the whole row. Is there any way to show clicked cell is being dragged.